# Matrix wherever you find a string replace by 1 then increment by 1 otherwise found null put 0 and show the new matrix JavaScript for loop generic code

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, matrix

Hey guys in short i have this 4x4 Matrix input

```
Matrix = [
  ["X", "X", null, null],
  [null, "X", "X", "X"],
  [null, null, "X", "X"],
  ["X", "X", null, null],
];
```

we wanna have as an output a new Matrix for instance for rows, wherever you find an "X" put 1 then in each "X" increment by one otherwise null replace it with 0 and continue from 0 we should have an output like that

```
output Matrix : [
  [1, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [0, 0, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 0, 0],
];
```

we should do 4 outputs (Matrix)s one for rows, one for columns and one for first then one for second diagonal

Output diagonal should be :

```
left to  bottom right diagonal means \ output = [
  [1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 2, 2, 1],
  [0, 0, 3, 3],
  [1, 1, 0, 0],
];

right to bottom left diagonal means / output = [
  [1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 2, 1],
  [1, 3, 0, 0],
];
```

no matter how much excecution time but should be readable generic and easy snippets as possible avoiding complexity i did the rows and stuck on diagonals with for loops if possible here my code:

```
const Rows = (matrix) => {
  let inc = 0;
  return matrix.map((array) =>
    array.map((_, ind, list) => {
      if (list[ind] == player) {
        inc += 1;
        return (list[ind] = inc);
      } else {
        inc = 0;
        return (list[ind] = 0);
      }
    })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give the code for top-left to bottom-right diagonal. You can do the similar for top-right to bottom-left diagonal.

```js
let Matrix = [
  ["X", "X", null, null],
  [null, "X", "X", "X"],
  [null, null, "X", "X"],
  ["X", "X", null, null],
];
let rows = 4,
  cols = 4;
  
// this is making an array of 4 arrays inside of it filled with null
let OutputMatrix = [...new Array(rows).keys()].map((x) => [...new Array(rows).keys()].map((i) => (i = i + x * rows)));

//i goes from last row to first row.
let counter = 1,
  i = rows - 1,
  j = 0,
  k = 1;
while (i >= 0) {
  while (i < rows && j < rows) {
    if (Matrix[i][j] != "X") {
      counter = 0;
    }
    OutputMatrix[i][j] = counter++;
    i++, j++;
  }
  j = 0;
  ++k;
  i = rows - k;
}

//j goes from second column to last column
(i = 0), (j = 1), (k = 1), (counter = 1);
while (j < cols) {
  while (i < rows && j < cols) {
    if (Matrix[i][j] != "X") {
      counter = 0;
    }
    OutputMatrix[i][j] = counter++;
    i++, j++;
  }
  i = 0;
  k++;
  j = k;
}

console.log(OutputMatrix);
```

Comment: Yeah i'll try to make it work for the second one thanks you so much just working on columns then i'll do it

Comment: something is going wrong I've posted what i've did  in the top

Comment: Thanks for the snippet i found the bugs in it and fixed them 
I will put the fixes in a moment

Comment: Thanks!  I missed the `j = 0;` in upper half. I rarely use javascript. I don't know it much so didn't do the variable declarations. Thanks for completing it. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Matrix.forEach(row => {
        var c = 0
        var rowIndex = Matrix.indexOf(row)
        row.forEach(value => {
            var valueIndex = row.indexOf(value)
            if (value === null) {
                c = 0
            }
            else{
                c++;
            }
            Matrix[rowIndex][valueIndex] = c

        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah thanks this is what i'm talking about but i'm stuck at diagonals and how to do them

Comment: Can you refine the problem or attach a picture?

Comment: @ofek: Your solution gives it row by row. OP has already given row by row solution. OP wants it diagonal by diagonal. I've given one possible solution.